# How can I add a classic portlet at the root of the portal when my product is installed?

Tags: plone, genericsetup

What is the simplest way to do this? I added it in the portlets.xml file in profiles/default. It is now available in the "Add portlet" dropdown when I go to @@manage-portlets. But I need it automatically created.

Is it possible to explicitly specify the set of portlets I want on the right and left columns inside my profiles/default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register your classic portlet trough the `portlets.Classic` portlet, configured with a template and macro name, using an `assignment` element in your portlets.xml file:

```
<assignment
    manager="plone.rightcolumn"
    category="context"
    key="/"
    type="portlets.Classic"
    name="my-classic-portlet"
    visible="1">
  <property name="template">templatename</property>
  <property name="macro">macroname-found-in-template</property>
</assignment>
```

See the [Portlets section of the GenericSetup manual on Plone.org](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/generic-setup/reference/portlets) or [the original PLIP](http://plone.org/products/plone/roadmap/203) for details on Portlet assignments and GenericSetup.

The properties match the portlet dataprovider interface, see the [Classic Portlet source code](http://dev.plone.org/plone/browser/plone.app.portlets/trunk/plone/app/portlets/portlets/classic.py#L12) for the interface definition for the Classic Portlet.

Answer (score 4):

The portlets.xml file does a few different things and there's a difference between registering a *kind* of portlet that can be added and actually adding a portlet, both of which can be done in portlets.xml.  You need to use an "assignment" element to add a portlet:

```
<assignment
   manager="plone.rightcolumn"
   category="context"
   key="/plone"
   type="plone.portlet.static.Static"
   name="foo-portlet">
  <property name="header">Foo Portlet Title</property>
  <property name="text">Foo portlet contents...</property>
</assignment>
```

Comment: sounds good. can this be done for classic portlets? can't seem to grep it in the source.

Answer (score 2):

For a not experienced product developer (even the others too) the easiest way to achieve this kind of automation is:

1. do manual configuration o
       assignment like a any other common
       plone user/administrator, going in
       the portal's root and adding the
       portlets you want.
2. go in zmi -> portal_setup -> export
   tab
3. select portlet step and export it
4. use portlets.xml in the tar.gz just
   got.

this xml contains all what you need: registrations and assignments... actually, even a little more stuff so may be a good thing to make a clean of what unneeded in it.

Comment: Yes.  I made exactly this recommendation the last time I saw a GenericSetup question.

Comment: Funny, for me it's often step 3.5: find the relevant data is not exported. (Possibly not in this case, though.)

Comment: it also generates loads of stuff depending on how people have been playing with their dashboard. Can be a pain to filter out the junk.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I said "the easiest" not "the better" ;)

Comment: Plus it doesn't seem to work. For eg. I don't want the login portlet. Export seems to give me the correct file. But when I install my product, the login portlet still remains. How do I get it explicitly removed?

Comment: Generic setup has an additive logic. This is the cause you still see login portlet. I don't know what write in xml to remove something. I these cases i write my own setuphandler step to grab portlet assignments in a specific context and fix the situation.
Here you can find a hint: http://pastie.org/1867241
HTH